# Getting single element with similar xpaths but with different same level, "neighboring" node

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to get the xpath of an element with a similar xpath to others but has a "neighbor" element that's different . Please see example below.

```
<div>
   <div id='a'> </div>
   <span> Text here </span>  #this is what i'm trying to get
</div>
<div>
   <div id='b'> </div>
   <span> Text here </span>
</div>
```

I tried using `//div//span`, but this gives me the 2 spans. So i tried using `//div//child::div[@id='a']//ancestor::div//child::span`, but it doesn't look pleasant and looks repetitive. Does this have a better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
//div[div[@id='a']]/span
```

it says get the `span` child node of all `div` nodes with child node div (with an @id equal to 'a').

Comment: Correct answer. Or `//div[div/@id='a']/span`